# Yammer API with poll results

Tags: api, yammer

I am trying to use the yammer api to get the messages and display it to the user.
I notice that the poll information on the json, does not return the result of a poll, even after the user has answered it. It only returns the options.

The api that I used
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json

Any ideas how to get the results?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**I couldn't find anything official**.
Playing and sniffing my interactions on the yammer page I found out that the page makes this call to retrieve the results:

METHOD: **POST**
**https://www.yammer.com/api/v2/messages/** *{{your_poolId}}*

and pass this code to the body:

```
feed(threads(messages(poll_options(option,answer,count,selected))))
```

it returns something like this:

```
{"messages":
 [{"id":{{your_poolId}},
 "poll_options":[{"option":0,"answer":"a"},
  {"option":1,"answer":"b"},       
  {"option":2,"answer":"c","count":1,"selected":true},
  {"option":3,"answer":"d"}]}]
}
```

Hope it helps,
Cheers

Comment: Do you (or anyone) have any additional information for this? Google led me here, of course :)